# Why can't I find all pattern matches with python regex?

Tags: python, regex

This problem seems so simple, but I can't figure out why I'm not getting all matches. The string I'm dealing with is "c.1292_1294delTTCinsA". I want to extract four patterns using nested groups: "del", "delTTC", "ins", and "insA". I've tried re.match, re.findall, and re.finditer without success. Here is my code:

```
    >>> s = 'c.1292_1294delTTCinsA'
    >>> m = re.findall(r'c\.\d+_\d+((del|ins)[AGCT]+)', s)
    >>> m
    [('delTTC', 'del')]
```

If I add the '+' operator on the end, I get the other two expected matches:

```
    >>> m = re.findall(r'c\.\d+_\d+((del|ins)[AGCT]+)+', s)
    >>> m
    [('insA', 'ins')]
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Unless I'm missing something, the two patterns do not overlap.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex requires the group to be directly preceded by `c\.\d+_\d+`.  The "ins" part of your string is not directly preceded by this material (it is preceded by "delTTC").  When you add the extra `+`, you allow a sequence of such groups, so it finds the del group and then the ins group, but later repeats of the group "overwrite" earlier ones, so only the last one (the "ins" part) is returned.

Do you actually need to match the beginning part of the string?  You could just make your regex `((del|ins)[AGCT]+)` and it will find all four parts.

Comment: Ah, of course. I knew it was something silly. Thanks!